# Snowflake CASE statement using file format?

Tags: teradata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Following is a Teradata case statement that converts `false, False, F, f to 0` and `true, True, T, t to 1` else `my_col_` value, I would like to do the same using Snowflake [file format.](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html)

```
CASE WHEN my_col ='\N' THEN NULL
 WHEN my_col = 'false'  OR my_col = 'False' OR my_col = 'F' OR my_col = 'f' THEN '0'
 WHEN my_col = 'true'  OR my_col = 'True' OR my_col = 'T' OR my_col = 't' THEN '1'
 ELSE my_col END as "my_col_"
```

Comment: So is your question, "how do I write CASE statements" or "how do I do any transforms in loading stage" because the form does not need the latter, and the latter does not need the former.

Comment: The question is already in the post, "I would like to do the same using Snowflake file format." @SimeonPilgrim

Comment: I appreciate you repeating the same words, and expecting a different response. A file format is just telling snowflake how to read a file, nothing more nothing less. What you are wanting todo is the  COPY INTO a table from a file soruce (eg S3) using a file format : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html , which called a LOAD opperation, so it seems your real question should be "how do I transform data as I load it, without having to land in a tempory table".. thus why I was asking if you are asking a LOAD question or a TRANSFORM question.

Answer (score 0):

if its case statement, it could be simplified as :

CASE WHEN my_col ='\N' THEN NULL
 WHEN my_col IN ('false','False','F','f') THEN '0'
 WHEN my_col in('true' ,'True','T','t') THEN '1'
 ELSE my_col END as "my_col_"

Answer (score 0):

Hoping by "Snowflake file format" mean you just need equivalent Snowflake query for above tearadata code and you really don't mean those 6 different file format that Snowflake supports. in That case.:

Considering my_col contains string data , same teradata code should work fine . Little compact version of above code can be as below

```
 CASE WHEN my_col ='\N' THEN NULL
 WHEN my_col IN ('false','False','F' ,'f') THEN '0'
 WHEN my_col IN ('true' , 'True' ,'T' ,'t') THEN '1'
 ELSE my_col END as "my_col_"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually modify your statement to something like this if possible:

```
CASE WHEN TRY_TO_BOOLEAN(my_col) = True THEN '1'
     WHEN TRY_TO_BOOLEAN(my_col) = False THEN '0'
     ELSE NULL END
```

If your target table is already a BOOLEAN field, then this will do it as well without the need for a CASE statement:

```
TRY_TO_BOOLEAN(my_col)
```

And as Simeon said in the comments, this can be done directly in the COPY INTO statement, if necessary, but has nothing to do with a FILE FORMAT.  Also, I would recommend you load the data raw, and then transform the data inside of Snowflake, instead.  It will perform better that way.

Comment: Thanks @Mike for the response, when you say "load the data raw" do you mean load it first in the external table and then load to the table?

Comment: I was trying to separate the transformation logic from loading the table, in the FILE FORMAT, there is `NULL_IF` I wonder if I can also have a user-defined function like this.

Comment: Not an external table.  I'd load it to a temporary table in Snowflake, first, and then apply the logic on the way from that temp table to your persistent target table.  And no, NULL_IF is just to null out things like \N or values of 'null'.  It's just a string in the file format definition.